# Reading text file in yaml for key-value pairs

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml

I have txtfile(textData.txt) which contains key-value pairs like :

```
user1: john
user2: bob
user3: william
```

Number of value pairs are dynamic, it can be one, two, three or more than three, but there will be at least one value pair in my txtFile.

I want to read this text file in my yaml file in such a way that I should get the output of yaml like :

```
- name: "User Names"
  users:
    - userid: user1
      username: john
      something: false
    - userid: user2
      username: bob
      something: false
    - userid: user3
      username: william
      something: false
```

I want this structure to be dynamic, depends on how much value-pairs are there in my textFile but something will remain constant and it won't be present in file. Please help me in it with example.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a dictionary and use *dict2items* to create the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: textData.txt
        name: users_dict
    - set_fact:
        users: "{{ users_dict|dict2items(key_name='userid', value_name='username') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  users:
  - userid: user1
    username: john
  - userid: user2
    username: bob
  - userid: user3
    username: William
```

---

, or put it into a file, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |
          ---
          - name: "User Names"
            users:
            {{ users|to_yaml|indent(width=2) }}
          ...
        dest: users.yml
      vars:
        users: "{{ users_dict|dict2items(key_name='userid', value_name='username') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat users.yml 
---
- name: "User Names"
  users:
  - {userid: user1, username: john}
  - {userid: user2, username: bob}
  - {userid: user3, username: william}

...

shell> yamllint users.yml
```

---

, or use Jinja to iterate the list, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        content: |
          ---
          - name: "User Names"
            users:
          {% for k,v in users_dict.items() %}
              - userid: {{ k }}
                username: {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
          ...
        dest: users.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat users.yml 
---
- name: "User Names"
  users:
    - userid: user1
      username: john
    - userid: user2
      username: bob
    - userid: user3
      username: william
...
shell> yamllint users.yml
```

Comment: I tried first solution and I went to my windows power shell and did cat users.yml and in output I got the code as it is without processing anything.

Comment: How I can add one more default value in Matcher like -     
    - userid: user1
      username: john
      regex: false
    - userid: user2
      username: bob
      regex: false