# Reading and Parsing Textfile in yaml

Tags: shell, ansible, yaml

I have txtfile(textData.txt) which contains key-value pairs like :

```
user1: john
user2: bob
user3: william
```

Number of value pairs are dynamic, it can be one, two, three or more than three, but there will be at least one value pair in my txtFile.

I want to read this text file in my yaml file in such a way that I should get the output of yaml like :

```
- name: "User Names"
     users:
       - userid: user1
         username: john
       - userid: user2
         username: bob
       - userid: user3
         username: william
```

I want this structure to be dynamic, depends on how much value-pairs are there in my textFile. Please help me in it with example.

I have tried few solutions but nothing worked for me.

**Solution 1**

My Sh File :

```
declare -A usernames=(["user1"]="john" ["user2"]="bob" ["user3"]="william")
for i in "${!usernames[@]}"; do
    echo "$i: ${usernames[$i]}"
done
ansible-playbook plays/username_play.yml
ans_sts=$?
if [ $ans_sts -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "E: FAILURE: Failed"
   exit 0
fi
```

Ran this sh file like

```
./file.sh > /tmp/set_matchers.txt
```

and I got the output like in txtFile as:

```
user1: john
user2: bob
user3: william
```

My Play File(username_play.yml):

```
---
- name: Usernames
  hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - import_role:
      name: UsernameScript
      tasks_from: username_task
    run_once: true
```

My Task File(username_task.yml)

```
- set_fact:
    users_dict: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/set_matchers.txt')|from_yaml }}"

- name: "Users Name"
    users: "{{ users|default([]) + [item] }}"
    loop: "{{ users_dict|dict2items }}"
    someOtherKey: "someOtherValue"
```

I just have to loop the matchers in body, not someOtherKey. Its going wrong as per my structure so need help in it to write in correct way.

**Solution 2**

I know I am skipping few things and not presenting the actual data bcoz of security reasons but I am trying my best to present the similar structure.
Till my play file, everything is working fine for me. Problem I am getting in task file only, so tried another solution suggested by other guy:

Task File(username_task.yml)

```
- include_vars:
        file: /tmp/set_matchers.txt
        name: username_dict

- name: "Users Name"
    users:
  {% for k,v in username_dict.items() %}
       - userid: {{ k }}
         username: {{ v }}
  {% endfor %} 
    someOtherKey: "someOtherValue"
```

Please help me in writing the right code for my task file.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: as reported in a comment on your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67336378/9401096), I think I finally understood what you are trying to do exactly by reading your 3 questions on the same subject in the last 24 hours and updated the below solution accordingly. In the future please edit your questions to make them match your requirements rather that multiplying them. Thanks.*

---

Questions references (beside this one):

- [Reading text file in yaml for key-value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67330824/reading-text-file-in-yaml-for-key-value-pairs)
- [Jinja2 format for iterating dictionary in ansible yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336378/jinja2-format-for-iterating-dictionary-in-ansible-yaml)

Doc references for below code:

- [`dict2items` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists)
- [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#map)
- [`combine` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries)

Given the file `files/textdata.txt` (which is actually a valid yaml file representing a dict)

```yaml
user1: john
user2: bob
user3: william
```

The following  `playbook.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: dict2items and map/combine demo
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    # This will be added to each user in the list
    user_default_values:
      age: N/A

    # Creating list of users from file and adding defaults
    user_dict_list: >-
      {{
        lookup('file', 'textdata.txt')
        | from_yaml
        | dict2items(key_name='id', value_name='name')
        | map('combine', user_default_values)
        | list
      }}


  tasks:
    - name: Show result
      debug:
        var: user_dict_list
```

Gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [dict2items and map/combine demo] ***************************************************

TASK [Show result] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "user_dict_list": [
        {
            "age": "N/A",
            "id": "user1",
            "name": "john"
        },
        {
            "age": "N/A",
            "id": "user2",
            "name": "bob"
        },
        {
            "age": "N/A",
            "id": "user3",
            "name": "william"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```